# Intersection of significant differences

Tags: statistical-significance, overlapping-data

My data are signals in which each data point represents a pair of time point and location on the brain. I have a categorical variable with three levels: conditions A, B, and C.

I have run non-parametric permutation tests to check whether condition A is significantly different than condition B, whether condition A is significantly different than condition C, whether condition C is significantly different than condition B. The results give me information about when and where in the brain the conditions are significantly different.

Now, I would like to use a statistical test or equation which can prove that, if I look for example for common significant differences between conditions A and B, and between conditions A and C, the intersection represents the differences associated with having condition A.

Something like A-B ∩ A-C = A.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by *the intersection represents the differences associated with having condition A*? And what are these *common significant differences between conditions* that you are looking for?

Comment: So for example, if there is a significant difference between conditions A and B at time points 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and location X, and there is a significant difference between the conditions A and C at time points 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and location X. The common significant differences would be the time points 6,7,8,9,10. Somehow, these common differences need to be associated, I think, with something specific of condition A.